# Gradle vs Maven Compatibility with Struts 2

Tags: maven, struts2, gradle

Hi I am new to Java Web development and I want to know Can Struts 2 be used with `gradle` instead of `Maven` ? Is there any issue if I use Gradle or is there any benifit if I use Maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle is a build tool that reuse the same Maven folder structure. If your dependencies are expressed correctly in your Gradle build file, a Struts 2 project can be built without any issue using Gradle.

Comment: You mean I have to have both Maven and Gradle, So that Gradle could use Maven folder structure.. ? I am Just a starter and I just know about Maven and gradle that they are tools to handle builds and dependencies...

Comment: No, you don't need to have both. What Luciano means is that Gradle expects that your code and resources will be structured under the same directory structure as Maven does, so that in that regard they are very compatible. Since Maven was around from earlier on in the game and already provides a central place for all the open source libraries, Gradle and Ivy choose to be able to support this and re-use it. So, in essence, a) Gradle re-uses the existing Maven dependencies and b) follows the same directory structuring.

Comment: I will like to know what special does gradle offer than as compared to Maven ?